# Aframe from localhost to server

Tags: php, aframe

I have created a A-frame webVR and tested on my localhost xampp. I want to learn  how to take the localhost to become a up and running website. 
please suggest link, articles, tutorials for me to learn. 
I have researched similar post on stackoverflow, and seems like wordpresss is the solution? or not. There are too many contradicted and vague answers on google. Thats why I am posting this beginner question on stackoverflow in which a forum I trust.

Comment: Search for hosting solutions. EC2, DigitalOcean, gh-pages... Question is very broad, unlikely to get an answer. Not specific to aframe, php.

Answer (score 0):

While this question has nothing to do with either php or Aframe, I came across a system that might work for you. I have never used this system so I cant vouch for them, but it might be worth your while looking at them.

https://app.netlify.com/drop